# Merge partitions in linux without losing data

Tags: linux, partition

I'm on CentOS 7.
I have data in `vdb2`. In `vdb3`, `vdd` and `vde` I don't have data. Is it possible to merge all 4 partitions and assign one mount point (/data1) without losing data?

```
[user@hbase2 ~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
vda    253:0    0    50G  0 disk 
└─vda1 253:1    0    50G  0 part /
vdb    253:16   0   450G  0 disk 
├─vdb1 253:17   0  46.6G  0 part /mnt/10.1.14.83
├─vdb2 253:18   0 372.5G  0 part /data1
└─vdb3 253:19   0  30.9G  0 part 
vdc    253:32   0    20G  0 disk 
├─vdc1 253:33   0     4G  0 part /home
├─vdc2 253:34   0     4G  0 part /var/tmp
├─vdc3 253:35   0     4G  0 part /var/log
├─vdc4 253:36   0     4G  0 part /var/log/audit
└─vdc5 253:37   0     4G  0 part /var
vdd    253:48   0    20G  0 disk 
vde    253:64   0   250G  0 disk
```

```
[user@hbase2 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        50G   36G   15G  71% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  385M  3.5G  10% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdc5       3.9G  333M  3.4G   9% /var
/dev/vdc2       3.9G   16M  3.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/vdc3       3.9G  113M  3.5G   4% /var/log
/dev/vdb1        46G   53M   44G   1% /mnt/10.1.14.83
/dev/vdc1       3.9G  222M  3.5G   6% /home
/dev/vdc4       3.9G   82M  3.6G   3% /var/log/audit
/dev/vdb2       367G  242G  106G  70% /data1
tmpfs           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1002
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use LVM to put the four block devices into a pool, from which you can create a logical volume for your `/data` filesystem.

1. Create partitions on `vdd` and `vde`. Technically not required, but recommended.
2. Create an LVM volume group using the three unused partitions: `vgcreate vg0 /dev/vdb3 /dev/vdd1 /dev/vde1`
3. Create a logical volume: `lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n data1 vg0`
4. Create a filesystem on the logical volume. For example, using ext4: mkfs.ext4 -L DATA1 /dev/mapper/vg0-data1`
5. Remote the `/data1` filesystem in read-only mode, to make copying files safer: `umount /data` && mount -o ro /data1`
6. Mount the new filesystem at a temporary location: `mkdir /mnt/foo && mount -L DATA1 /mnt/foo`
7. Copy the files from `/data1` to the temporary mountpoint: `cp -av /data1/ /mnt/foo/`
8. Modify `/etc/fstab` so that it mounts `/data1` from the new filesystem (the logical volume from step 3.
9. Reboot and cross your fingers.
10. Verify that the new filesystem is being mounted at `/data1`.
11. Once you're satisfied, it's time to reclaim the old partition: `wipefs /dev/vdb2 && vgextend vg0 /dev/vdb2 && lvextend vg0/data1 -r -l +100%FREE`